# How to manipulate plots in spplot in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice, r-sp

I am trying to use spplot to visualize plots from different months. I'd like to change this figure so the same months are in the same columns to easily compare. I would like to push May 2016 5 panels in, so all the rest of the months are in line. I hope this makes sense. 
[click here for figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLtyD.png)

I have missing data for Dec2017 for now which is why it's blacked out.

Here is my code:

```
stack_months <- stack(May2016, June2016, July2016, Aug2016, Sep2016, Oct2016, Nov2016, Dec2016, January2017, Febuary2017, March2017, April2017, May2017, June2017, July2017, July2017, Aug2017, Sep2017, Oct2017, Nov2017, Dec2017, January2018, Febuary2018, March2017, April2018, May2018, June2017, July2017, July2018, Aug2018, Sep2018, Oct2018, Nov2018, Dec2018, January2019, Febuary2019, March2019, April2019, May2019, June2019, July2019, July2019)
spplot(stack_months, col.regions=viridis(20), names.attr = c("May2016", "June2016", "July2016", "Aug2016", "Sep2016", "Oct2016", "Nov2016", "Dec2016", 
                                                             "Jan2017", "Feb2017", "March2017", "April2017", "May2017", "June2017", "July2017", "July2017", "Aug2017", "Sep2017", "Oct2017", "Nov2017", "Dec2017",
                                                             "Jan2018", "Feb2018", "March2017", "April2018", "May2018", "June2017", "July2017", "July2018", "Aug2018", "Sep2018", "Oct2018", "Nov2018", "Dec2018", 
                                                             "Jan2019", "Feb2019", "March2019", "April2019", "May2019", "June2019", "July2019", "July2019"), layout = c(12,4))
```

Is there an easy way to manipulate the panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have type some of the months twice, for example July2017 appeared 3 times and March2017, 2 times, June2017 2x and July2019 2x.

What I have below are complete months from May2016 to July2019, so that when you plot, the months will align.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(viridis)
library(lattice)

months=c("May2016", "June2016", "July2016", "Aug2016", "Sep2016", "Oct2016", 
"Nov2016", "Dec2016", "Jan2017", "Feb2017", "March2017", "April2017", 
"May2017", "June2017", "July2017","Aug2017", "Sep2017", 
"Oct2017", "Nov2017", "Dec2017","Jan2018", "Feb2018", "March2018", 
"April2018", "May2018", "Jun2018", "July2018", "Aug2018", 
"Sep2018", "Oct2018", "Nov2018", "Dec2018","Jan2019", "Feb2019", 
"March2019", "April2019", "May2019", "June2019", "July2019")
```

I don't have your data, so I simulate something for the image:

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
stack_months = do.call(stack,lapply(months,function(i)runif(1)*r))
```

You defined layout to be 12,4 so you will have 48 entries which are filled by row. In your case, the first 4 will not be plotted and the last 5 will not be plotted:

```
SKIP = rep(FALSE,12*4)
SKIP[1:4] = TRUE
SKIP[44:48] = TRUE
```

Then we plot using the SKIP above:

```
spplot(stack_months, col.regions=viridis(20),
layout = c(12,4),
strip = strip.custom(par.strip.text = list(cex = 0.65)),
names.attr = months,
skip=SKIP
)
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to make the plot titles bigger? So make May2016, June2016, etc bigger?

Comment: Hi @AnnaWindle, you try something like below? Basically you have to cex for par.strip.text, but in order to see the increase font size, you have to play around with aspect and parameters of the strip text

Comment: stripParams <- list(cex=2, lines=1.5) ;
spplot(stack_months, col.regions=viridis(20),
layout = c(12,4),
strip = strip.custom(par.strip.text = list(cex = 0.9)),
names.attr = months,
par.strip.text = stripParams,
skip=SKIP,aspect="xy"
)